# Exponential equation with absolute value: $9^{|3x-1|}=3^{8x-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

$$9^{|3x-1|}=3^{8x-2}$$

Can someone show me the steps on how to solve this, i've been trying for 30 minutes

Comment: $|6x-2| = 8x-2$.

Comment: can you tell me more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $$\large 9^{|3x -1|} = 3^{(2\cdot|3x - 1|)} = 3^{8x - 2}$$
So we need only solve
$$\begin{align}2\cdot |3x - 1| = 8x - 2 & \iff |3x - 1| = 4x - 1\\ \\ & \iff 3x - 1 = 4x - 1 \quad\text{or}\quad-(3x - 1) = 4x - 1\end{align}$$

Comment: so how do you solve $|3x - 1| = 4x - 1$? sorry im really bad

Comment: See the edit: there are two solutions for $x$. Solve each case separated by "or" separately.

Comment: im getting $x = 0$ and $x = 1/6$, neither of those are right

Comment: You're right that we have to throw out $x = 0$. But double-check your solution to the second case: I get $x = \dfrac 27$

Comment: you're right i turned 3x into 4x for some reason, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$x^a=x^b \implies a=b$

$|x|=a \implies x= \pm a$.